# how to run swift timer in background

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i use this timer in ma swift app

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(didTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But after i update my iPhone to 14.1 timer doesn't work in background. Any solution for it?

Comment: do you keep the reference to the Timer object? It may be getting deallocated instantly after running the code above

Comment: yes, i keep ```private var timer: Timer!``` in my class, in below ios 14 everything is working

Comment: try calling the `Timer.scheduledTimer` but not the one with selector but rather use the block `(Timer) -> Void` one and see if it makes any difference

Comment: nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You can save the time that app before goes to background. When App come to foreground you can calculate passed time and set timer or update text.

Comment: of course but i would like to make a sound alert after some time so i must have a timer in background, any idea for it?

Comment: You can set notification or alert to time that rest of the time on timer. If app comes foreground before alert trigger, you can delete alert or notification. Or whatever you want to do. @AdamNowak

Comment: i used 

`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+60.0, execute: {
            self.onCompleted()
        })`


and it is also doesn't work, This function was called after i back from background. Any idea tor this?